# Insert previously entered command into file

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, insert, command

## What I'm trying to do

In a Bash terminal on Mac OS 10.15.4, I'm trying to insert a command I have previously executed into a script file.

## How I'm trying to do it

I print the command I previously entered using the command below.

```sh
!700:p
```

I then try to insert it into my script file using the command below.

### Input

```sh
!700:p >> script_file
```

### Output

```sh
'command I'm trying to insert' >> script_file
```

Alas, it is not inserted into *script_file*.

Any help would be most appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: I don't have mac OS with me so couldn't test, could you please try following once `history | tail -n 2 |head -n 1` assuming you have `history` command in it.

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13, it returns 726  'command I entered'

Comment: So is it good?You needed your last command only correct?

Comment: What if you use `tee`,  `!700:p | tee -a script_file`  I have disabled history expansion a very long time ago so I can't really say that it will work ^^.

Comment: hi @Jetchisel, sadly it still did not insert.

Comment: @chefchaouen, didn't my command work for you? it worked for me in linux.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, no, I want to insert the command into "script_file," not just print the command entered out.

Comment: @chefchaouen, simple, try `history | tail -n 2 |head -n 1 > script_file` run and lemme know then? Once you are happy I can add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get details of previous ran command into a output file try following.

```
history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 > script_file
```

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13, I have a lot of commands in my history and I am not very good at mental math so I don't want to have to mentally calculate the difference between the current command history index number and the previous command I want to insert. Sorry...

Comment: @chefchaouen, but you mentioned that you need last/previous command so I had written this, is there anything else you are looking? Or this command is working fine and you are looking for explanation(which I will add in few mins)/

Comment: Your answer would be fine if I only wanted to insert the command I JUST entered, however if the command I want to insert was from a long time ago then I would have to calculate how many times ago it was for your answer to work.

Comment: @chefchaouen, your question thread says `Insert previously entered command into file` so request you to please keep 1 question 1 thread only, you could open a new question for same,so that future users will not be confused IMHO.